# multiple instance of activity is created every time while sending values to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using fire-base database to sync my local data.
Whenever I upload data to fire-base database from asynctask new sign in is done every time and new activity instance is created.
it only happens when I upload data and not when I download data.

Comment: I found my error. I had "valueEventListener" set to my root node in my login activity than was causing the problem.

Comment: Good to hear that you found your problem Dharak. For future questions be sure to include the [minimal code that reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to increase your chances of getting help.